# webprofiler not working on clean symfony4 project

Tags: php, symfony, xampp, profiler

I've got a strange problem going on with Symfony. Today I made brand new project using `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton gall` command and right after installation, before doing anything in code I go to the website and the only thing that is said on webprofiler toolbar is "An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar." I don't even get to see what kind of error is this.

The server I'm running is PHP v. 7.2.3, program is Xampp for Windows.
I thought maybe this default starting page is bugged, so I made some test controller and the error is exactly the same. 
Have you encountered such problem with latest symfony?

Comment: Nope. 4.1.1 seems to work as expected using "bin/console server:start"

Comment: When I start server, windows doesn't ask me for running it, page is loading non stop, so I guess local sever from symfony command don't start. Some time ago, when using Symfony3 I was always using XAMPP for PHP server and profiler toolbar wokred fine.

Comment: try to add /index.php in the url

Comment: I assume you installed the htaccess file?  It's no longer delivered by default.  Don't know what you mean by windows asking about running.  bin/console server:start should just work.

Comment: Yes, this looks like a rewrite error. Check your symfony logs and (more likely) apache-logs. The apache access logs should contains 404s for the profile url.

Comment: Thanks guys. Didn't think about .htaccess file, it was always delivered and I never looked into it. But Frank B answer worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would never figure it out myself, but adding index.php to browser address resolved the issue.

Much better solution is to use command

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack
```

As the .htaccess file is not included in the website-skeleton by default :)

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction guys!